# Using dgrid in form collections in a Zend Framework 2 application

Tags: php, dojo, zend-framework2, dgrid, zend-form2

For our new project, we have started using Zend Framework 2 and Dojo 1.8. ZF2 has a completely rewritten form module, which now features the new CollectionElement for one-to-many relationships. Regarding UI I find, that dgrid fits best for such relationships (using the editor column plugin), so I started extending FormCollection, FormRow and FormElement view helpers, so they can render the desired dgrid. Everything was fine until I realized, that I cannot set per-row input names for the dgrid widgets.

I started with the [ZF2 documentation rearding form collections](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.form.collections.html). One can see, that collection input elements have array-like names like

```
order[products][0][name]
order[products][0][price]
order[products][1][name]
order[products][1][price]
```

On the other hand, dgrid's configuration is column based, so I can have a column definition like

```
editor({
    field: "_dojo_textbox_505ee3a390d705_26717315", 
    label: "Name",
    editorArgs: {
        name: "order[products][{index}][name]",
    }
}, TextBox)
```

This column definition will define set the same widget name for all rows, which does not work with the ZF2 collection data format requirement.

What I also tried is naming the column like this:

```
order[products][]
```

which works, but does not allow the desired format

```
order[products][][name]
```

Maybe there is a way to post the data like this:

```
order[products][name][]
```

and have it converted afterwards, but the solution doesn't looks right. Beside this I am trying to produce reusable code and want to avoid per-form data modifications.

Since I am trying very hard to avoid onSubmit/onClick event handling for data conversion, there are 2 possible solutions:
1. Make dgrid able to set per-row widget names
2. Make ZF2 form understand some other-than-standard POST format for collections

Unfortunately I ran out of ideas, how either of those solutions can be done, so I will be most thankful, if you can give me a hand with this!

Since this is somewhat related with my current question, I will place it here as a side question:
What other than this UI solution do you use for your one-to-many form interfaces with dojo?

Answer (score 1):

In Zend framework version 2 , "Zend\Form" itself has the capability to add new elements to the "Collection element" dynamically.

You can check it [here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.form.collections.html#adding-new-elements-dynamically)